# How to access elements in nametuples in python?

Tags: python, tuples, namedtuple

I'm confused about accessing elements in `namedtuple` in python, say I have

```
Container = namedtuple('Container', ('mac_0', 'mac_1'))
```

Can I use `Container[0]` and `Container[1]` to access the first element `mac_0` and the second element `mac_1 ?`

Comment: [The docs] (http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) say that it's pretty close to that. `c = Container(mac_0=true, mac_1=false)` then `c[0]` etc. or `c.mac_0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access elements either by index, or by name ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)):

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Container = namedtuple('Container', ('mac_0', 'mac_1'))
>>> container = Container(mac_0=1, mac_1=2)
>>> container[0]
1
>>> container[1]
2
>>> container.mac_0
1
>>> container.mac_1
2
```